# Convex combination

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuos function. Let $x_1,x_2,x_3\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\in[0,1]$ such that $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=1$. I am trying to prove that there exists $u,v\in\mathbb{R},\beta_1,\beta_2\in [0,1],\beta_1+\beta_2=1$ such that 
$$\beta_1u+\beta_2v=\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2+\alpha_3x_3$$
$$\beta_1f(u)+\beta_2f(v)\le\alpha_1f(x_1)+\alpha_2f(x_2)+\alpha_3f(x_3)$$

If I use Caratheodory theorem in Convex analysis, I can do it. My question is that can we prove this problem by only using the continuity of $f$ ?